# Convert this Btree Index from Postgres to Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql

I am familiar with Oracle's `Create Index` statement and I'm expected to convert these particular Index definitions (obtained from `\d+ tab_name)`  to Local indexes in Oracle. I have to convert these index definitions exactly in Oracle.

```
"ind_typ1_name_uniq"   UNIQUE, btree (col1, col2) WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL

"ind_typ2_uniq" UNIQUE, btree (col3, col2) WHERE col1 IS NULL
```

I explored a bit and found function based indexes in Oracle may be needed, but not sure how exactly I could convert this.Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may probably use an equivalent function based index with `COALESCE` or `NVL` to mimic this partial index in Postgres.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ind_typ_uniq ON
    yourtab_name ( coalesce(
        col1,
        col3
    ),
        col2
    );
```

This will not create two different Partial Btree indexes as in Postgres. However the optimizer can use an index range scan on a function-based index for queries  which contain such expressions in `WHERE` clause.

Since you want `LOCAL INDEX` you may specify the LOCAL keyword at the end. But, note that the partition key should be present as a subset of the list of columns, since it is defined as a `UNIQUE` index.